# Extracting username from email using Python pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I'm trying to read bunch of email addresses from a CSV file and extract usernames from these email addresses using Pandas but getting the following error message instead.

**ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index**

Here is my code which is not complex.

```
import pandas as pd
import sys

input_file = sys.argv[1]

data_frame = pd.read_csv(input_file)

data_frame['Username'] = data_frame['Email Domain'].str.split("@")[0]

print(data_frame)
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks,

Comment: What's the *full* stack trace and can you provide a sample of your CSV file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strictly trying to explain what you are doing wrong

```
data_frame['Email Domain'].str.split("@")[0]
#           splits the strings /           \ points to the first row of result
```

Solution

```
data_frame['Email Domain'].str.split("@").str[0]

0       abc
1       xyz
2    blah24
Name: Email Domain, dtype: object
```

***setup***
Thanks A-Za-z

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'username': ['abc@gmail.com', 'xyz@yahoo.com', 'blah24@gmail.com']})
```

Comment: @piRSquared, Thank you for your response. It worked!

Comment: @Inquisitive Feel free to upvote answers that were useful.  Even if you don't accept an answer, its always appreciated when you up vote to indicate that the answer was still useful.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'username': ['abc@gmail.com', 'xyz@yahoo.com', 'blah24@gmail.com']})
```

You can use str.extract to get the usernames like this

```
df.username.str.extract("(.*)@")
```

You get

```
0       abc
1       xyz
2    blah24
```

Compare this with

```
df.username.str.split("@")[0]
```

You get first row

```
['abc', 'gmail.com']
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Both your and piRSquared's answers worked.